# How to build a simple Donut Chart using D3js and Angular 7

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular7, donut-chart

I am creating a Donut chart in Angular using D3.js v5. All other simple graphs like bar-graph, circles, lines etc. work properly, but the "pie()" function gives some error. Can anyone suggest me how to use the pie() function properly in Angular?

**I am getting errors in below mentioned scenarios.**

1. while setting color domain, it doesn't accept data, it says, it needs `ReadOnlyArray<String>`, so tried giving hardcoded domain `["a","b","c","d","e"]`
2. `pie()`--> Doesn't accept values, no idea why, tried a lot here.
3. `this.color(d.data.key))` --> `this.color` doesn't accept access data and key.

**Need to resolve all the above-mentioned issues.**

#### the code goes as follows :

```
export class DonutChartComponent implements OnInit {

    width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40
    radius;
    svg;
    color;
    pie;
    data_ready;

    // Create dummy data
    public data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}


    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    this.draw();

    }


     draw(){

     this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - this.margin


     this.svg = d3.select("app-donut-chart")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("width", this.width)
               .attr("height", this.height)
               .append("g")
               .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + 
                this.height / 2 + ")");



     // set the color scale
     this.color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(this.data)             // this.data gives error here
           .range(d3.schemeDark2);

     console.log(d3.scaleOrdinal());

     // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
     this.pie = d3.pie()
               .value(function(d) {return  d.values});     //error here
     this.data_ready = this.pie(d3.entries(this.data))

      this.svg
     .selectAll('whatever')
     .data(this.data_ready)
     .enter()
     .append('path')
     .attr('d', d3.arc()
     .innerRadius(100)         // This is the size of the donut hole
     .outerRadius(this.radius))
     .attr('fill', function(d){ return(this.color(d.data.key)) })  
                                                           //error here
     .attr("stroke", "black")
     .style("stroke-width", "2px")
     .style("opacity", 0.7)
    }
}
```

I expect if the code runs properly I can see a donut chart based on the data given.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things wrong:

1. Your color scale's `.domain` is expecting a list of strings.  Modify to:

   `.domain(Object.keys(this.data))`
2. Your pie generator should be defined as:

   `this.pie = d3.pie()
      .value(function (d) { return d.value })`

Now it [works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvzqdv).

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - this.margin;

    this.svg = select("pie-chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width)
      .attr("height", this.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," +
        this.height / 2 + ")");

    this.color = scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(Object.keys(this.data))
      .range(schemeDark2);

    console.log(scaleOrdinal());

    this.pie = pie()
      .value((d) => d.valueOf());
    this.dataReady = this.pie(entries(this.data));

    this.svg
     .selectAll("whatever")
     .data(this.dataReady)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", arc()
     .outerRadius(this.radius))
     .attr("fill", (d) => (this.color(d.data.key)))
     .attr("stroke", "black")
     .style("stroke-width", "2px")
     .style("opacity", 0.7);
```